# Android: how to make image wider than screen

Tags: android, xml

I want to create rotate animation of ImageView in Android. Because image is a square, so I need to make its width larger than screen width. Fixed size doesn't work. When I start playing with different scale type, I get a square which width is exactly the same as the device's width or I get the rectangle (height is the same as device's height, but the width is cropped, so animation doesn't work as I want). Is it possible to set bigger width? Thanks!

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="2000dp"
        android:layout_height="2000dp"
        android:src="@drawable/stars"
        android:id="@+id/stars"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't test it. This is of the top of my head

1) Subclass your `ImageView` and override `onMeasure()` method.

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    setMeasuredDimension(YOUR_TARGET_WIDTH, YOUR_TARGET_HEIGHT);
}
```

2) Set the `layout_width` and `layout_height` parameter of the parent view of this `ImageView` as `WRAP_CONTENT`.